# SQL query - Trying to figure out SQL statement

Tags: sql, many-to-many, subquery

I'm trying to write a query to request the names of the employees that have contacted 'Wegmans Food Markets'.

**Company**
CompanyID
CompanyName

**Contact**
CompanyID
FirstName
LastName

**Contact-Employee**
ContactEmployeeID
ContactID
EmployeeID

**Employee**
EmployeeID
FirstName
LastName

I've trying to write subqueries, but since I am a beginner I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: "You should always provide complete code examples (e.g. schema, data sample and expected result) in your question or answer."  For your table definitions, please provide complete CREATE TABLE statements, including any foreign keys that these tables define.  Also, what SQL statements involving subqueries have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define an extra table.You can put EmployeeID as foreign key in Contact table.

Company CompanyID CompanyName

Contact CompanyID FirstName LastName,EmployeeID(foreign key)

Employee EmployeeID FirstName LastName

Every Employee has a contact and every contact has a company.

Select E.FirstName from Employee E inner join Contact C on E.EmployeeID=C.EmployeeID inner join Company P on C.CompanyID=P.CompanyID where P.CompanyName="Wegmans Food Markets"

Answer (score 0):

Select E.FirstName From Employee E, Contact-Employee Ce, Contact C, Company D Where E.EmployeeId = Ce.EmployeeId, Ce.ContactId = C.ContactId, C.CompanyId = D.CompanyId and D.CompanyName = "Wegmans Food Markets" group by E.FirstName